# Is procreation a sin?

Tags: nature-of-god

> The concept that this world is bent and fallen is pretty standard in
>   just about every form of Christianity. **That this world is not what God
>   intended it to be** is the starting port. But the hope of the Gospel is
>   that this suffering is not the end.

From @AffableGeek in His answer to: [How does Christianity explain suffering that ends in death?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15026/how-does-christianity-explain-suffering-that-ends-in-death/15029#15029)

If the world is no longer what God wanted it to be, only **after the fall** I assume, does He delight in bringing new life to such a world in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, but I have to VTC as not constructive based on this meta post's reasoning:  http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1486/what-to-do-with-is-x-a-sin-questions  BUT, since God told us to go forth and multiply, the answer is a clear "no."  Sin is defined as disobedience to God.  Obedience is therefore not sin.

Comment: @DavidStratton: ok fair enough, and that is actually a really good answer, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing as the very first commandment God gave Adam and Eve was "Be fruitful and multiply," that would be difficult to go with. Potentially, you might say, "we'll, that was before the Fall!"  But, then again, after the flood, God commands Noah to do the same thing.

In general, you need to get beyond this idea that *suffering* is evil. It's not what we like, and it may not even have been God's first plan- but in His sovereignty, he can use it for His glory.

Suffering is the means that God uses to put Hope within us. If that suits His purposes, then it's fine with me. (Just don't ask me to like it!)

Comment: quick question, God said this to Adam and Eve - who says he is saying that to us - I would imagine that is very debatable....?